# Wake On LAN does not work when PC shut down - only when it is suspended

Tags: 20.04, power-management, wakeonlan

For some reason Wake Up On LAn doesn't work for me in Ubuntu when PC was shut down but only when it was put to sleep using

sudo systemctl suspend

My network card does support wake on lan

I also checked the interface setup using the below

```
~$ sudo ethtool enp6s0
[sudo] password for dmytro:
Settings for enp6s0:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        MDI-X: off (auto)
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

Any ways to fix this?